# Inserting two different TIME in single column with AM/PM format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have following table

```
 E(E_id(pk),
    E_date (datetime),
    E_time (datetime)
   ,E_Title (varchar (50))
```

I am trying to insert DATE and TIME in the above Table using following code:

```
INSERT INTO E(E_Date,E_Title,E_Time)
VALUES('12/10/2017','Every day is a Big day','11:00 am-13:00 Pm')
```

I executed above code, but SQL is giving me an ERROR Saying
**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**
I would like to insert the DATE and TIME in the above format.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `datetime` column type can't store a time range. I think E_date should be `date` and you need separate time columns like E_starttime and E_endtime, each with data type time.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for advice. I was wondering if there is a way I can tweak code to show me 11:00 . SQL is currently displaying "11:00:00:000000"  I just want SQL to display 11:00 ? Is it possible to code it like that way ?

Comment: You can specify the desired fractional seconds precisions with `time`. Specify `time(0)` if you don't need sub-second precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server's `datetime` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) is meant to store a "point in time", i.e. one day and one time.

Quote from the link:

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day with fractional seconds that is based on a 24-hour clock.

Your code has multiple problems:

1. The string `11:00 am-13:00 Pm` is not a valid `datetime` value, that's why your query is failing.
2. As the `datetime` type contains a time as well, so `'12/10/2017'` will actually be saved as `12/10/2017 00:00`.

---

So I guess your current table design is not what you actually want.

There's no type in SQL which can hold a "timespan" like 11am-13pm.

As a `datetime` is actually a "point in time", it's better to use *two* datetime columns, one for the start and one for the end of your timespan.

When you insert into the table, you specify both date **and** time for both columns.

Then, you can use (for example) the [`DATEDIFF` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) to calculate the timespan between the two datetimes.

Here's a complete example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[E](
    [E_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [E_start] [datetime] NULL,
    [E_end] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into E (E_start, E_end)
values
('2017-12-10T11:00:00', '2017-12-10T13:00:00'),  -- starts and ends on the same day
('2017-12-10T09:00:00', '2017-12-11T10:00:00')   -- starts and ends on different days

select *, DATEDIFF(hh, e_start, e_end) as HoursPassed from e
```

Result of the last query:

```
E_id        E_start                 E_end                   HoursPassed
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
1           2017-12-10 11:00:00.000 2017-12-10 13:00:00.000 2
2           2017-12-10 09:00:00.000 2017-12-11 10:00:00.000 25

(2 rows affected)
```

---

To write a query which shows the time as `11:00`, you can use [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) if you want just the time:

```
select convert(char(5), e_start, 108) from E
```

...or [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

```
select format(e_start, N'hh\:mm') from E
```

Comment: ..Thanks for Explanation. I was wondering if there is a way I can tweak code to show me 11:00 . SQL is currently displaying "11:00:00:000000" I just want SQL to display 11:00 ? Is it possible to code it like that way

Comment: .I know it must be simple but if possible can you please show me how to show query result as "11:00 am" instead of "11:00 only"